# how to return an exception from async in asp.net webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, model-view-controller, exception

I have a WebAPI2 mvc app where I'm doing Get/Post to another api. My code looks like below

```
   public Task<SomeEntity> AddAsync(SomeEntity someEntity)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = apiService.PostItem(url, someEntity);

            if (response == null || response!="Successful")
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(response);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Error " + ex.Message);

            // how to return this error or exception;

        }
        return Task.FromResult(someEntity);
    }
```

If the call to the internal api return an exception string then I need to forward it from this method call. Any ideas how can I do it? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use IHttpActionResult or HttpResponseMessage as your return type and return proper HTTP-Status codes. In case of exception you can return [if you return IHttpActionResult ]

```
public IHttpActionResult Error()
{
    var error = new HttpError();
    return ResponseMessage(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, error));
}
```

or as in your example, throw HttpResponseException with appropriate status code.

```
public Product GetProduct(int id)
{
    Product item = repository.Get(id);
    if (item == null)
    {
        var message = string.Format("Product with id = {0} not found", id);
        throw new HttpResponseException(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, message));
    }
    else
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I can't change my return type to IHttpActionResult

Comment: Use the second approach in that case.